# Determine the three maximum and two minimum values of the array

Tags: arrays, c, max, min

Task:

> Given a natural number N (set arbitrarily as a preprocessor constant) and one-dimensional array A0, A1, …, AN-1 of integers (generate positive and negative elements randomly, using the `<stdlib.h>` library function `rand()`). Perform the following actions: Determine the three maximum and two minimum values of this array.

Code with search for two minimum values:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 9

int main() {
    int M[N], i, a[N], fbig, sbig, tbig, min, smin;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        M[i] = rand() % 20 - 10;
        printf("%i\t", M[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (a[i] < min) {
            smin = min;
            min = a[i];
        } else
        if (a[i] < smin && a[i] != min)
            smin = a[1];
    }            
    printf("\nMinimum=%d \nSecond Minimum=%d", min, smin);
    
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to compare array elements with each other but here is my result:

```
-7  -4  7   5   3   5   -4  2   -1  

Minimum=0 
Second Minimum=0
```

I would be very grateful if you could help me fix my code or maybe I'm doing everything wrong and you know how to do it right. Thank you for your time

Comment: Have you tried running your code line-by-line in a debugger while monitoring the control flow and the values of all variables, in order to determine in which line your program stops behaving as intended? If you did not try this, then you may want to read this: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/12149471) You may also want to read this: [How to debug small programs?](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Other than `M` none of your variables are initialized or set to anything leaving their values indeterminate.

Comment: Your logic isn't right.  Suppose min=3 and smin=5.  Then you see a new value, 2.  Your code will set min to 2, which is wrong.  It needs to replace the larger value, which is in smin, not the smaller value.

Comment: Also, you never initialize min, smin, etc. so the entire thing will exhibit undefined behavior.  What do you think `a[i] < min` will do when `min` is undefined?  No one can say.  It's a severe bug.  Just initialize them to the first two values in the array, then start your loop on the third element.

Comment: What should it return for N < 5?  You either need to sort your minimum and maximum values or you have to potentially look at all of them for each entry of the array.  I suggest you use arrays instead of individual variables.  I would also advise you to use functions instead of having all your logic in main().  The usual convention is to use upper for constants (N is ok but not M is not).

Comment: Quickselect doesn't even need to sort, but you could use statistics to do this problem without even creating the array to begin with, (although, that's not really useful for nine elements.)

Comment: What is the expected output for the input you provided?  In particular for the maxima is the result [7, 5, 5] or [7, 5, 3]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will revise my answer if op address what to do about duplicate values.  My answer assume you want possible duplicate values in the minimum and maximum arrays, while other answers assume you want unique values.

The easiest solution would be to sort the input array.  The minimum is the first 2 values and the maximum would be the last 3:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAX_N 3
#define MIN_N 2
#define N 9

void generate(size_t n, int a[n]) {
    for(size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        a[i] = rand() % 20 - 10;
}

void print(size_t n, int a[n]) {
    for(size_t i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
        printf("%d, ", a[i]);
    if(n) printf("%d\n", a[n-1]);
}

int cmp_asc(const void *a, const void *b) {
    if(*(int *) a < *(int *) b) return -1;
    if(*(int *) a > *(int *) b) return 1;
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    int t = time(0);
    srand(t);
    printf("%d\n", t); // essential for debugging

    int a[N];
    generate(N, a);
    print(N, a);

    qsort(a, N, sizeof *a, cmp_asc);
    print(MIN_N, a);
    print(MAX_N, a + (N - MAX_N));
}
```

If you cannot use sort then consider the following purpose built algorithm.  It's much easier to use arrays (`min` and `max`) rather than individual values, and as a bonus this allows you to easily change how many minimum (`MIN_N`) and maximum (`MAX_N`) values you want.  First we need to initialize the `min` and `max` arrays, and I use the initial values of the input array for that.  I used a single loop for that.  To maintain the invariant that the `min` array has the `MIN_N` smallest numbers we have seen so far (`a[0]` through `a[i-1]`) we have to `replace()` *largest* (`extrema`) of them if the new value `a[i]` is *smaller*.  For example, if the array is `min = { 1, 10 }` and the value we are looking at is `a[i] = 5` then we have to replace the `10` not the `1`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAX_N 3
#define MIN_N 2
#define N 9

void generate(size_t n, int a[n]) {
    for(size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        a[i] = rand() % 20 - 10;
}

void print(size_t n, int a[n]) {
    for(size_t i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
        printf("%d, ", a[i]);
    if(n) printf("%d\n", a[n-1]);
}

int cmp_asc(const void *a, const void *b) {
    if(*(int *) a < *(int *) b) return -1;
    if(*(int *) a > *(int *) b) return 1;
    return 0;
}

int cmp_desc(const void *a, const void *b) {
    return cmp_asc(b, a);
}

void replace(size_t n, int a[n], int v, int (*cmp)(const void *, const void *)) {
    int *extrema = &a[0];
    for(size_t i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        if(cmp(extrema, &a[i]) < 0) {
            extrema = &a[i];
        }
    }
    if(cmp(extrema, &v) > 0)
        *extrema = v;
}

void min_max(size_t n, int a[n], size_t min_n, int min[n], size_t max_n, int max[n]) {
    for(size_t i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        if(i < min_n)
            min[i] = a[i];
        else
            replace(min_n, min, a[i], cmp_asc);
        if(i < max_n)
            max[i] = a[i];
        else
            replace(max_n, max, a[i], cmp_desc);
    }
}

int main() {
    int t = time(0);
    srand(t);
    printf("%d\n", t); // essential for debugging

    int a[N];
    generate(N, a);
    print(N, a);

    int min[MIN_N];
    int max[MAX_N];
    min_max(N, a, MIN_N, min, MAX_N, max);
    print(MIN_N, min);
    print(MAX_N, max);
}
```

and here is example output.  The first value is a the seed in case you have to reproduce a run later.  Followed by input, min and max values:

```
1674335494
-7, 0, -2, 7, -3, 4, 5, -8, -9
-9, -8
7, 5, 4
```

If `MIN_N` or `MAX_N` gets large, say, ~1,000+, then you want sort the `min` and `max` arrays and use binary search to figure out where to insert`a[i]`.  Or use a priority queue like a heap instead of arrays.

Comment: I'm afraid you do not address the OP's task precisely: *Determine the three maximum and two minimum values of this array.* Instead you output the three maximum and two minimum elements of the array, which may be different in case of duplicates.  The assignment is somewhat ambiguous... You might specify this in your answer to justify your approach.

Comment: @chqrlie Your assertion is that values must be unique.  Do you have a reference for that?  I may very well be wrong.  In other words we determine the maximum value from our our array.  Then remove all the elements from the array with that value.  Then select the maximum from the set.  If that's the behavior they want for determining maximum why do we allow duplicates in the array in the first place?

Comment: @chqrlie I don't necessarily mean to imply that is how you would implement it (it would be a minor tweak similar to what Dúthomhas does below).

Comment: IMHO the assignment is ambiguous: *three maximum values* may mean the 3 maximum distinct values or the values of the 3 largest elements, possibly with duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

As already noted, the most direct way to do this would be to simply sort the array. (In fact, if all you need is an output of five integers then your array only need be five elements long.) But I will presume that that is not the point of this homework.

<sup>Your goal isn’t super efficiency or a pretty algorithm. It is simply to solve the tasks. Do them one at a time.</sup>

---

**First question**: How would you find the *largest* value?

Answer: Loop through the array, keeping track of the largest element found so far.

```
int largest = array[0];  // why start with this value?
for (int n = 0;  n < size;  n++)
  if (array[n] > largest)
    largest = array[n];
```

---

**Second question**: How would you find the *smallest* value?

Answer: Almost the same way, with only a simple change: Instead of testing if `(array[n] > largest)` we want to test if `(array[n] < smallest)`, right?

```
int smallest = largest;  // why start with this value?
for (int n = 0;  n < size;  n++)
  if (...)               // new condition goes here
    smallest = array[n];
```

---

**Third question**: How would you find the *second smallest* value?

Answer: It should not surprise you that you just need to change the `if` condition in that loop again. An element would be the *second smallest* if:

- it is the smallest value *greater than* the `smallest`.

Think about how you would change your condition:

```
int second_smallest = largest;  // why start with this value?
for (int n = 0;  n < size;  n++)
  if (... && ...)               // what is the new test condition?
    second_smallest = array[n];
```

<sup>Remember, this time you are testing *two* things, so your test condition needs that `&&` in it.</sup>

---

**Fourth question**: can you write another loop to find the second-largest? How about the third-largest?

At this point you should be able to see the variation on a theme and be able to write a loop that will get you any **N**<sup>th</sup> largest or smallest value, as long as you already have the (**N**-1)<sup>th</sup> to work against.

---

Further considerations:

- Is it possible that the third-largest is the same as the second-smallest?
- Or the smallest?
- Is it possible for there to *not* be a third-largest?
- Does it *matter?*

Put all these loops together in your `main()` and print out the results each time and you are all done!

```
...
int main(void)
{
  int array[SIZE];
  // fill array with random numbers here //

  int largest = array[0];
  for (...)
    if (...)
      ...

  int smallest = largest;
  for (...)
    if (...)
      ...

  int second_smallest = largest;
  for (...)
    if (...)
      ...

  int second_largest = smallest;
  for (...)
    if (...)
      ...

  int third_largest = smallest;
  for (...)
    if (...)
      ...

  printf( "The original array = " );
  // print original array here, then: //
  printf( "largest      = %d\n", largest );
  printf( "2nd largest  = %d\n", second_largest );
  printf( "3nd largest  = %d\n", third_largest );
  printf( "2nd smallest = %d\n", second_smallest );
  printf( "smallest     = %d\n", smallest );
  return 0;
}
```

Example outputs:

```
{ 1 2 3 4 }
smallest     = 1
2nd smallest = 2
3rd largest  = 2
2nd largest  = 3
largest      = 4
```

```
{ 5 5 5 5 5 }
smallest     = 5
2nd smallest = 5
3rd smallest = 5
largest      = 5
```

```
{ 1 2 }
smallest     = 1
2nd smallest = 2
3rd smallest = 2
largest      = 2
```

Bonus: be careful with variable names. There has been no need to use short abbreviations since before the early nineties. Prefer clarity over brevity.

Comment: You will need to remember which, of possible duplicates, is part of your result set, so you can skip those on subsequent passes.  Or mutate the input by partitioning it.

Comment: @AllanWind That’s part of answering the third question, and very easy.

Comment: Well, I am obviously missing something then if it's that simple.  Say, your  input is {1, 2, 1, 3 } so you find the smallest which is easy.  Now you need to find the 2nd smallest how know to skip a[0]?  Unless you mutate the array and start at a different index.  The 2nd smallest `a[2]` is not greater (`>`) but greater-and-equal to (`>=`) the minimum value.

Comment: You don’t need to skip testing any particular element. Also, pay attention to which value we _start_ with. We first found the largest _and_ smallest. (You are thinking too hard. ;-)

Comment: Possible.  Prove it :-)  My guess is that you assume either unique input or output.

Comment: Alas, I can’t make it any simpler without just giving away the answer. I’ve got to get some sleep. Maybe you should do the same and look at it again when you have fresh eyes...

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- `min` and `smin` are uninitialized, hence the comparisons in the loop have undefined behavior and the code does work at all. You could initialize `min` as `a[0]` but initializing `smin` is not so simple.
- there is a typo in `smin = a[1];`  you probably meant `smin = a[i];`

Note that the assignment is somewhat ambiguous: are the maximum and minimum values supposed to be distinct values, as the wording implies, or should you determine the minimum and maximum elements of the sorted array?

- For the latter, sorting the array, either fully or partially, is a simple solution.
- For the former, sorting is also a solution but further testing will be needed to remove duplicates from the sorted set.

Here is a modified version to print the smallest and largest **values**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define N      9
#define N_MIN  2
#define N_MAX  3

void swap(int *a, int *b) {
    int tmp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = tmp;
}

int main() {
    int a[N], i, j, e, dup;
    int smallest[N_MIN], nsmall = 0;
    int largest[N_MAX], nlarge = 0;

    srand(time(NULL));

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        a[i] = rand() % 20 - 10;
        printf("%i\t", a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        e = a[i];
        dup = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < nsmall; j++) {
            if (e == smallest[j]) {
                dup = 1;
                break;
            }
            if (e < smallest[j]) {
                swap(&e, &smallest[j]);
            }
        }
        if (!dup && nsmall < N_MIN) {
            smallest[nsmall++] = e;
        }
        e = a[i];
        dup = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < nlarge; j++) {
            if (e == largest[j]) {
                dup = 1;
                break;
            }
            if (e > largest[j]) {
                swap(&e, &largest[j]);
            }
        }
        if (!dup && nlarge < N_MAX) {
            largest[nlarge++] = e;
        }
    }
    printf("smallest values: ");
    for (i = 0; i < nsmall; i++) {
        printf(" %d", smallest[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("largest values: ");
    for (i = nlarge; i --> 0;) {
        printf(" %d", largest[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```